# Container storage location with specified provisioning code not available

Tags: amazon-s3, object-storage

On creating a bucket using s3 API, I get the

> Container storage location with specified provisioning code not available (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidLocationConstraint; Request ID: f377cc84-2e76-490b-8161-4407a4b8d9d7), S3 Extended Request ID: null error.

However, I can create a bucket using the service portal on Softlayer. Programmatically I can get the latest list of buckets and even delete it, but creation throws the above error.

Answer (score 0):

A recent update has introduced unintended behavior around bucket creation, and we're working to fix it. The system is expecting a Location Constraint of `us-standard`.  Provide the following XML block in the body of the request:

```
<CreateBucketConfiguration> 
  <LocationConstraint>us-standard</LocationConstraint>
</CreateBucketConfiguration>
```

If using an SDK, you'd follow the conventions of the particular library you are using. For example, using `boto3` creating a new bucket might look like this:

```
bucket = s3.create_bucket(Bucket='my-bucket',
                          CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': 'us-standard'})
```

In java, it would look like:

```
s3.createBucket(bucketName, "us-standard");
```

Here's a [link to the docs](https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/crs-api-reference.html#providing-a-location-constraint) (we're steadily improving them).

Let me know if that doesn't help, or if you are using another tool or SDK. :)

Comment: creating a bucket with [ibm-cos-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm-cos-sdk) `s3.createBucket` does not work, even when running the code sample. Following error is replied:
"message": "Container storage location with specified provisioning code not available",
"code": "InvalidLocationConstraint"

Comment: are you sure that the endpoint chosen during client creation matches the `LocationConstraint` value?